# Rails: how to use conditions and only let the db look 100 records deep, I'm not looking for limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, find, conditional-statements

I'm adding data to a db and I only need to check for duplicated data within the last 30 minuets or so.

Data is getting added at about 10 entries per minuet so I only need search about 300 records. How can I get this in conditions with rails Model.find(:all, :conditions => [])?

Comment: Are you inserting the records using Rails? If not then while inserting directly you should make sure that you add timestamp to the record.

Comment: What version of Rails do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model.find(all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 30.minutes.ago])

Comment: How does the db know if a record was create 30 min ago?

Comment: While creating a new record, rails by default adds a timestamp to created_at and updated_at columns...

Comment: internally active record generates SQL query like Select * from TABLE where created_at > (Time.now - 30 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition based on the age of the data. For instance 'created_ad > ?', 30.minutes.ago

Comment: same thing as with Jagira, does sql have to loop over all records to find the age of the record?

Comment: Depends on your table setup. In general yes, but you can add an index (even a clustered one if your db supports it and you don't have other queries/indices) on that column, so the database will not do a full table scan. The usefulness of an index would also depend on the sizes of your rows and the size of your database overall (eg. there is no point in using an index if you don't have enough data in your table)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer, but the Rails API may have changed. I'm using 3.1.3. This worked for me:

```
Model.where(:updated_at => (30.minutes.ago.utc)..Time.now.utc)
```

UTC part would depend on how you're storing your dates.